# Do I need a Multisite?

Tags: multisite

I have a client who has asked me to develop a sales-based WordPress site with a customized subdomain for each potential client (http://client1.website.com; http://client2.website.com; etc.).

Is a multisite the way to accomplish this or is there a better way?

Thank you!!
Angie

Comment: This may answer your question: [Before You Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client asks for multi-sites, there is no alternate option for it then.

But according to the need, sometimes creating separate pages for clients like website.com/client1/, website.com/client2/ etc. and masking/redirecting client1.website.com, client.website.com to these (respectively) may work as well.

This will lessen the trouble of handling multiple sites.

Comment: Thank you! This will work. The client didn't request a multisite but I didn't realize redirecting was an option. I just found a tutorial on how to do that. This will save me lots of table space as Rick mentioned could be a problem down the road and it will save me creating multiple copies of the media library. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Multisite was created for.  You could have a separate WordPress install for each subdomain, but you are multiplying the maintenance to keep plugins, themes and the core up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The way explained by joetek is fine, cause turns it easy to maintain a single base updated for everyone! But, depending on the solution you are figuring out, also has an cons: once you have a single instalation, a single bunch of code, in order to serve many clients, if this single point of failiure presents some problem (bug, virus, hackers) its ging to affect all your potential clients... In my case I have something like that, and i have dockerized every client with its own linux+apache+wordpress, and with its own linux+mysql database. And everything behind a nginx reverse proxy. This way i have a little bit more effort to update all wordpresses, but a little bit more secure too. And my customers also can ask for sftp access because its not going to affect main repo. I dont know how wp multisite handles this question of sftps.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a multisite solution to me.

But be aware that each sub-site will create an additional 8-10 tables in your database. Some hosting places will get irritated if you have a database with 100 tables or more, especially with the cheaper hosting plans. In my experience, a multisite with more than 10 subsites will start to get the attention of a hosting place if you are on their cheaper plans.

So be aware of the need for a higher level of hosting plan because of the number of sub-sites you will have.

Of course, if the client is hosting the site on their own server, then you just need to make sure that the server has the 'horsepower' (resources) to handle the visitor load.

Comment: Thank you, Rick. All the tables could become a problem down the road. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks... glad to help. (clicking the up arrow and the checkmark to indicate a correct/helpful response)